# Mongo DB BI Connector with Tableau not working with sharded instance

Tags: tableau-api

I've been trying to follow these instructions https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_mongodb.html#make_cx

to get the tableau desktop to connect to my mongo db server. looking at the data source example in the link above they only have 1 server listed where I have a replica set, which I think might be an issue.

i was wondering if anyone has an example connecting tableau to mongo where mongo is on a replica set?

Answer (score 0):

It should work.  When you setup the Mongo BI Connector, you can specify a standard Mongo URI connection string with multiple replicas. However, when connecting from Tableau, you specify the hostname of the server where the Mongo BI Connector service is running.  It will use the uri connection string you defined.

See: https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/reference/mongosqld/#cmdoption-mongosqld-mongo-uri

Comment: Thanks Jon. Unfortunately, I'm no longer exploring Tableau as an option.